# Is it appropriate to use leading zero in C# assembly version?

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, .net-assembly, assemblyversions

I am setting assembly version for my dot net dll

Assmebly version has below format,

> **"major version.minor version.build number.revision"**

I am setting Verison like below,

```
200.1.1.0;
```

Now my question is do I need to keep a leading zero in minor version,build number and revision number `(200.01.01.00)`  Or without leading zero `(200.1.1.0).` Which is right practice? Is there any Microsoft guideline available ? I didn't find any guidelines by Googling.

Answer (score 8):

The versions are stored internally as integers, so even if you append 0 to the start of the version number, it will be converted to an int and removed.

Answer (score 1):

Both the way you can use

(200.01.01.00) or (200.1.1.0)